# Supplying RDiff Base File Using Pipe Results in Illegal Seek Error

Tags: pipe, patch, rdiff

If I run the following rdiff command

```
rdiff patch basefile patchfile outputfile
```

everything works as expected, however, if I try to use stdin to provide the base file like this

```
xz -d -c basefile.xz | rdiff patch - patchfile outputfile
```

I get the following errors

```
librsync: ERROR: (rs_file_copy_cb) seek failed: Illegal seek
librsync: ERROR: (rs_job_complete) patch job failed: IO error
librsync: ERROR: IO error
```

The man page clearly states

```
In every case where a filename must be specified, - may be used instead to mean either standard input or standard output as appropriate.
```

Is the man page incorrect, or am I doing something wrong? Is it possible to provide the base file to rdiff using a pipe?  Any other way to provide the basefile to rdiff via the xz command without creating a temporary file which isn't an option for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: It looks like the man page is wrong, it should say "**almost** every case" and mention that`rdiff` needs to seek its "basefile", so that file can't be provided by pipe or process substitution.   stdin seems to work ok for providing delta and signature files, seems they don't need to be seeked.   I'd suggest submitting a bug report but it looks like you [already have](https://github.com/librsync/librsync/issues/218)